ChatterBot not installed on IDLE 3.7.9
I've installed ChatterBot 1.0.0 (due to the unavailability of the other versions) with pip:
pip install chatterbot==1.0.0

and for some reason, IDLE is returning with this output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\greatbot.py", line 1, in <module>
    from chatterbot import ChatBot
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chatterbot'

I opened up IDLE with the search bar (Windows 10)
I tried this as a test:
from chatterbot import ChatBot

chatbot = ChatBot("Bot")

exit_conditions = (":q", "quit", "exit")
while True:
    query = input("> ")
    if query in exit_conditions:
        break
    else:
        print(f" {chatbot.get_response(query)}")


But, my main question is how do I get chatterbot onto IDLE 3.7.9?

how are you opening idle and how did you install chatterbot? Please post the commands you are using.

Does the output of pip --version indicate the version of pip in your PATH matches the version of IDLE you're using (3.7.9)?

try installing using same python that you use for executing the code python -m pip install chatterbot==1.0.0
You can also run directly from the python
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\bin\python -m pip install chatterbot==1.0.0

@esqew No. It doesn't. It's 3.11.

@JohnnyCheesecutter If you meant the Python Shell, it had a syntax error. If you meant the command prompt, chatterbot was downloaded. Yet, it still did not function.

@ThatRandomGuy By default, using a version of pip that doesn't match with the interpreter you're using 3.7.9 will cause issues, since the interpreter will be looking in an entirely different folder for your dependencies. You should be able to use the pip version that's tied to the version of Python you're attempting to use to run your code - pip3.7 install chatterbot==1.0.0. Alternatively (my preferred invocation): python3.7 -m pip install chatterbot==1.0.0
